# SQL - Most Recent Time Stamp for Each User

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, netezza, aginity

I have a table with a user Account,the current status of the account and the Timestampe of any changes made to the status. When i run the following command for 2 specific accounts it brings back every date & time a change has occured but i only need the most recent date and time for each account.

When i try to include a Group BY ACCOUNT i get the following error:

"must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function"

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
select ACCOUNT, Status,LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
from ACCOUNT_ROLE 
where ACCOUNT in (123456789,987654321);
```

Comment: Se [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group by `ACCOUNT` and get the maximum last update timestamp for each account you could try the following SQL:

```
select ACCOUNT, MAX(LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP)
    from ACCOUNT_ROLE 
    where ACCOUNT in (123456789,987654321) -- this is an optional filter clause.
    group by ACCOUNT
```

You will have to leave out the `STATUS` field from the select clause.

Assumptions: `LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP` is datetime type field.

Comment: Thats correct, LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP is the date a change occurred, at the moment with my current code every date is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using GROUP BY clause. i think u are trying to display values by ordering of ACCOUNT. If so user **Order by** ACCOUNT

Comment: select ACCOUNT, Status,LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
from ACCOUNT_ROLE 
where ACCOUNT in (123456789,987654321) ORDER BY ACCOUNT;

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the output to the most recent date ? rather than displaying every date a change occurred for each Account. Example output below:

123456789 ACTIVE 2012-07-07 12:39:07
123456789 ACTIVE 2018-05-21 06:10:47
123456789 ACTIVE 2018-05-23 06:53:16
123456789 ACTIVE 2018-05-23 06:53:16
987654321 ACTIVE 2013-01-25 12:42:53
987654321 NEVER 2012-05-24 07:35:34
987654321 ACTIVE 2012-05-26 08:56:46
987654321 ACTIVE 2017-03-23 07:08:48